# Jest: no code coverage available outside of root directory

Tags: code-coverage, jestjs, babel-jest

In Jest we have the ability to point to different test directories. This includes directories outside the current application.

example:

```js
base-ui-----------|
    /tests--------|
       file.test.js
    /package.json
------------------|
site-ui-----------|
    /tests--------|
    /dist---------|
------------------|
account-ui--------|
    /tests--------|
    /dist---------|
------------------|
```

The package.json in base-ui runs all the tests. 
it contains the "jest" config with "testPathDirs"

```js
"testPathDirs": [
    "<rootDir>/tests",
    "../../../../site-ui/tests",
    "../../../../account-ui/tests"
],
```

When I try to point the "collectCoverageFrom" to the same locations, it doesn't work.

```js
"collectCoverageFrom": [
    "**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "../../../../site-ui/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "../../../../account-ui/**/*.{js,jsx}",
    "!**/node_modules/**",
    "!**/vendor/**"
],
```

I understand babel-istanbul takes the cwd, but I would presume that I would be able to back out a few levels.

Any idea why these globs wouldn't work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems if I remove `/tests` from the `"testPathDirs": []` the relative paths work.

It is summed up nicely in a comment by @cpojer in an issue unde jest's github
https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/1211#issuecomment-246466808